# Export Magento database to a custom db schema

Tags: php, mysql, magento, database-migration

I'm developing a custom PHP/MySQL web ecommerce site. My client has asked to migrate existing Magento db data to the new database. I have dumped existing product data to .csv file. I'm thinking of reading the .csv file in PHP and extract the cell data in the way I need. However, there may be various complications when handling images, custom columns...etc. And I'm not using Magento EAV model for my database.

I guess there may be practical difficulties to migrate the entire database. I would like to know the advice of experts in order to handle this scenario .successfully.

Comment: It depends on how your new web commerce is structured. From my point of view, you could create the sql tables inside Magento DB and build custom scripts to populate those tables with what you want. Then simply export/import tables inside your project. It's much more simpler to use existing Magento php functions than work on tables directly. At least that's an option i'd consider.

Comment: Thanks, this seems more helpful.